# How to get list of object with relation OneToMany

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

How to get list of object with relation OneToMany with typeorm with using queryBuilder?

I need to get this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Bob",
  "lastName": "Sparrow",
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Very Big Order"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Big F*** Order"
    }
  ]
}
```

i try with this:

```
const user = await this.conn
  .getRepository(User)
  .createQueryBuilder("user")
  .leftJoin("user.orders", "orders")
  .select("user.orders", "orders")
  .getRawMany();
```

but this not return me an aray of all objects :/

Comment: What does it return then?

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = await this.conn
.getRepository(User)
.createQueryBuilder("user")
.leftJoinAndSelect("user.orders", "order")
.getMany()
```

Would this solve your issue?

Comment: why return me `orders: [ [Order] ],`  instead of objects in this array?